# gradle create dependency for maven, build fails

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-plugin

I want to create a sample dependency from project in gradle to project to maven

```
apply plugin: "maven-publish"
apply plugin: "java"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'java'
        }

        resources {
            srcDirs 'build'
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from 'build/libs'
    classifier = 'sources'
}

publishing {

    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'or.gradle.sample'
            artifactId = 'sort-array'
            version = '1.1'

            artifact sourcesJar
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

but when I type:

```
gradle publishToMavenLocal
```

I have in log :

```
... Publishing to repository null ....
```

and BUILD FAIL

Comment: Please add the exact error messages you get to your post

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'mavenLocal'
   > org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainerException: Cycle detected in component graph in the system:

Comment: I stupid! has gradle v 2.10. After update all fine work=). Question may close!